# Transferring large data in a data migration

Tags: c#, c++, optimization, networking, network-programming

We have a set of applications that transfer data from one system to another within the same network. They uses WCF C#, and do something like transfer 1000 objects at a time on a continuous basis. (after receiving data, receiver application notifies sender to send more data)

I am wanting to optimize the process by transferring more data in a given time, and  am thinking which of the following 2 options is better:

1. Increase transfer quantity significantly. The bigger the better, make it like 50000 objects. This will reduce the time spent per data in moving from user process space to network card, by doing it in bulk.
2. Make transfer quantity to be just less than 1460, which is our network path MTU. eg., if an object is 100 bytes, transfer 12 objects leaving some allowance for http and soap headers. this will avoid reassembling of TCP segments and speedup the receipt. (it will avoid excessive RAM usage problems)

Can you please tell which option is better, or if I can try some other idea to speedup the transfer?

Comment: whatever you do make sure if your end points are both .NET to use TCP Transport, it's the fastest of all

Comment: K lvanov - thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is the speed of transferring to the network card.

Please tell us more about this data migration 
  -- Is it coming from a flat file?
  -- Are you changing the data at all?
  -- What type of data do you need at the other other end?

I'm guessing -- but I expect you must be changing the data.  If you just need to move data there are many fast ways to move a big file (eg ftp or some other standard).

If you are changing the data it is probably that process that is slowing you down -- run a profiler on your program and optimize it.

Comment: source data is measurement data messages from equipments. we transform the data in C# code. algorithm does not take much time, and it's latency can be reduced by running more programs in parallel. please assume that at the moment my main bottleneck is on the network serialization and transferring side.

Comment: PS: we are trying to improve the process from all sides, and will be ok to spend our time and effort in the networking side

Comment: You are converting the data to SOAP to transmit it to the target machine?  I would use a binary TCP transfer via WCF instead of SOAP.